# MembershipReboot vs Thinktecture Identity Model

Tags: c#, identity, thinktecture-ident-model, membershipreboot

What are the differences between MR and IM in terms of extensibility, stability, security and such?

Which one would be more preferable for a single tenant application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in no way comparable. MR is a library for user management. IdM is a helper library around the claims-based identity APIs in .NET

They work together really well though ;)